R package dev: Save local presistent database of logs
I am trying to create a package to be submitted to cran using the following idea that a user run analysis and the analysis is automatically appended to ~/analysis.RDS
So, ~/analysis.RDS is meant to be created once at start use the package, then it will not be recreated again.
For CRAN, this file cannot be created automatically expect in tempdir(), so user need to create a call to initialize_db() for the first time.
My question is, for package dev with some unit test, can I run initialize_db() with no CRAN violation?

I don’t think there’s any need to do that. Just get your append function to check for the existence of analysis.RDS. If it exists, append. Otherwise, create.

Use an argument  for destination file, perhaps set its default value to ~/analysis.RDS , but in tests use tempdir()? I don't think I'd personally be too impressed finding out that packages are creating files outside of project & tmp directories, especially when dealing with containers. In context of RDS, appending doesn't really work, does it? I mean, saveRDS()  / write_rds()  just overwrite the whole thing.
